# image size shrinks when window is resized

Tags: html, css, window-resize

I'm having an image in the layout, and when I resize the window it's size goes down and become too small.

I want to make the image fix at it's position and prevent it from become smaller and smaller as I shrink the window.

`HTML`

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #333333;padding-left:30px;">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 outsidediv">              
          <!-- image -->
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2  image" >
             <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/50JVVSZF/checkk.png" style="max-width:100%;" alt="img">
          </div>


          <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'>
              <h2 style="font-size:2rem;color:#666666;">
              <strong>
                   Some other Text alongside
              </strong></h2>    
           </div>

  </div>   

   </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.image{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    word-break:none;
    color:white;
```

}

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4tpgLcn/4/)

When you shrink the window size, the image size decreases, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static size with CSS: `width: 93px; height: 96px;`. You can either apply it to the '.image' class div or the image specifically. Here it is with inline CSS on the image tag:

```css
.image{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    word-break:none;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 outsidediv">              
          <!-- image -->
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2  image" >
             <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/50JVVSZF/checkk.png" style="width: 93px; height: 96px;" alt="img">
          </div>


          <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'>
              <h2 style="font-size:2rem;color:#666666;">
              <strong>
                   Some other Text alongside
              </strong></h2>    
           </div>

  </div>   

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By adding these lines to the image, it now squeezes the image, although the size don't go smaller.
I want  the image to be in it's form like it is being shown for medium or large screens, full square form, I want that but for now it behave like this.
see this.
https://jsfiddle.net/gq35nt6x/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete `max-size` and it will stay at the same size all the time.

```css
.bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
    .outsidediv{
     /*border:solid;*/
    }
    ul li{
  /*margin-left:15px;*/
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size:1.3rem;
    }
    #play{
     margin-top:35px;
    }
   
   .image{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     /*justify-content: center;*/
     
     /*font-size:2rem;*/


      align-items: flex-start;
  word-break:none;
  color:white;

   }
   #bt{
    margin-top:40px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-size:2rem;
   }
   nav{
    min-width: 100%;
   }
   body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Main page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- font awesome for the icons -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #333333;padding-left:30px;">

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 outsidediv">    
              <!-- image -->
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2  image" >
                 <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/50JVVSZF/checkk.png" alt="img">
              </div>


              <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'>
                  <h2 style="font-size:2rem;color:#666666;">
                  <strong>
                       Some other Text alongside
                  </strong></h2> 
               </div>

      </div>   
  
  </div>
</div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```